# Running PySpeech recognize_google on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, pypi

The problem is that PySpeech converts the audio to FLAC before it sends a request to the Google Speech API. When running on Heroku, PySpeech fails to find flac installed on the system to make a subprocess conversion call. What would be the best way to get around this?